# Is there anyway to change themes using a program?

Tags: themes, customization

This also means that the program can install themes by itself, because the main reason I don't want to change from the default theme is that I have to install the theme myself after downloading it

EDIT:
I want to be able to install theme using any theme manager (if there are any), but I don't want something where I'd have to install the theme myself and the theme manager would only change the thme

Comment: Can you please edit your questioin? I am unable to understand what you want to say.

Comment: let's see if I get it right: you want a theme manager that lets you preview, download, install and activate a theme from a list of available themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Epidermis theme manager](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/epidermis-theme-manager.html).  Epidermis combines wallpaper, GTK, metacity, icon, splash, usplash, cursor, grub and Xsplash themes in one GUI program.  Install Epidermis theme manager in Ubuntu, you can download it from [Here](https://edge.launchpad.net/epidermis/+download)

Also you may want to look at [Conky](http://itsfoss.com/conky-gui-ubuntu-1304/)

Answer (score 0):

As I know there’s no need to install a theme. It’s enough to copy the theme folder into `~/.themes` (create one if it doesn’t exist), and then open a customization program like MyUnity, Unity Tweak Tool, Ubuntu Tweaks, or Unsettings and select the desired theme.

For the icons, you should copy the folder containing all icons into `~/.icons`.